# Refresh/replay a non-loop .GIF animation

Tags: jquery, refresh, animated-gif

I really tried finding out a way to do this but I really couldn't...Is there a way to replay a non -looping .gif on a button/link click if that .gif is set from css as a background?

If it could be done using jquery it would be even better.